# angular - uirouter update optional param without reload

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I have a angular 4 app with multiple routes (ui-router) that accept optional params.

```
{ name: 'shirts', url:'/shirts/:color/:size, component: ShirtComponent }
```

This works but what I want to do is change some of the optional params on the click of a button. without reloading the entire page. I am looking for a way to update the params in the url.

I have spend hours looking for a solution but there are so many angular 1 answers and I don't get any wiser from the docs.

help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Try declaring parameters with **dynamic** flag.

As per documentation

> When dynamic is true, changes to the parameter value will not cause the state to be entered/exited. The resolves will not be re-fetched, nor will views be reloaded.

https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/interfaces/params.paramdeclaration.html#dynamic

---

Also since you want for parameters to be optional you need to declare them with the **value** flag, that

> Specifies the default value for parameter. This implicitly sets this
>   parameter as optional

https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/interfaces/params.paramdeclaration.html#value

All in all your parameters should look like

```js
{ 
  name: 'shirts',
  url:'/shirts/:color/:size, 
  component: ShirtComponent,
  params: {
    color: {
      value: null,
      dynamic: true
    },
    size: {
      value: null,
      dynamic: true
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Location` API's [`go`](https://angular.io/api/common/Location#go)/[`replaceState`](https://angular.io/api/common/Location#replaceState) method which belongs to `@angular/common`. They will just replace browser `history` without letting router know about it.

```
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

export class MyComponent {
    constructor(private location: Location) { }
    redirect(){
        this.location.go('/mypath');
        //OR
        //this.location.replaceState('/mypath');
    }
}
```

[**Demo Here**](https://plnkr.co/edit/PDF6oV2TQThqe0Yv98Np)

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I am looking for a way to update multiple params on button clicks (all individual) without reloading the page. With the solution above I can only go to a single path right?